# Is $|z-4|\geq |z|$ an open or closed region?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

After solving $|x+i y-4|\geq |x+iy|$ I found that $|z-4|\geq |z|$ if $x\leq 2$. Does this mean that $|z-4|\geq |z|$ is closed?

Comment: $|z-4|\geq |z|$ iff $x\le2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. An alternative way to formalize this, is to not that $f\colon z\mapsto |z-4|-|z|$ is continuous (because subtraction and absolute value are continuous) and hence our region $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ is closed because it is the pre-image of a closed set under continuous function.

Comment: @Hagon, but my teacher said that its not closed or open. Does this mean he is wrong?

Comment: @user3741635 We both independantly *proved* that the region is closed. Your teacher *said* it is not closed, but how would he *prove* it? - Note that I

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\lvert z - 4 \rvert \ge \lvert z \rvert \iff \\
\lvert z - 4 \rvert^2 \ge \lvert z \rvert^2 \iff \\
(x-4)^2 + y^2 \ge x^2 + y^2 \iff \\
-8x + 16 \ge 0 \iff \\
x \le 2
$$
so your solution set agrees with mine.

The question is how to characterize a *complex* set as open or closed.

According to [this definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203404/86776) it would not be open, because e.g. for $z=2$ we could not fit in a disc with positive radius around it and stay within the solution set.

Now for the [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Open_and_closed_are_not_mutually_exclusive) property:

$S$ would be closed if its complement is open. The complement would be
$$
S^C = \{ z = x + i y \mid (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x>2 \}
$$
and this one indeed seems open, as one can fit in positive radius discs around every point of $S^C$.

So the set $S$ is closed and not open.

Comment: It is closed because $(-\infty, 2]$ is closed.

Comment: By the definition you linked to (the usual one), the above set is closed.